# How can I treat org-agenda-custom-commands as an associative array?

Tags: org-agenda

Every time I run this, it gets added to the list, but I want to replace the entry "ab" with any new definition I come up with.

```
(setq hukarz
    `("ab"
      "foo bar"
      tags                   
      "+foo"
      (
       )
      ))

(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands hukarz)
```

Is there any way I can treat the list as an associative array, so that whenever I add something to the list, it updates the entry defined in the first parameter, just like "ab" in my example, which really is the shortcut in Org Agenda.

Comment: I presume you'd want this when testing a new entry. If so, I recommend you put the definition in a small file (say `test-agenda-comman.el`) that you can load again and again. The only thing you need to add is a `setq` at the top of the file to set `org-agenda-custom-commands` to `nil`. Then start a new emacs session with `emacs -q -l test-agenda-command.el` and test the new command out. Tweak it in the file and reload the file to test the ttweaked version: repeat as necessary. You can even keep the file under source control, so you can go back to previous versions.

Comment: When you are happy, copy the entry and the `add-to-list` to your init file where you define all your other entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely write custom code that will find and replace the entries in that data structure, but you do have to put the work into it.

Since org-mode iterates over `org-agenda-custom-commands`, and because of the complex way that it can be configured (see the help for this variable), doing this requires writing code that is slightly more than trivial. If you do the work, though, it will very likely be valuable to the community :)